# Android Array String

Tags: android, arrays

Hi guys if i try to assign the string to string Array i am getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION..
Pls give me a solution..

Here is my code and i am getting null pointer in this line   thumbs[j]=title;
as code Follows...

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
        Node item = items.item(i);
        NodeList properties = item.getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < properties.getLength(); j++) {
            Node property = properties.item(j);
            String name = property.getNodeName();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                try{
                    property.normalize();
                    Spanned title2 = Html.fromHtml(property.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().replaceAll("\\<.*?>", ""));
                    title =  title2.toString();  
                }catch(Exception e){
                     Log.v("Exception",""+e);
                }
                thumbs[j]=title;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where did you initialize `thumbs`? Can you show us please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possibility is that thumbs is null. It isn't a compile error if you don't initialize it. Don't rely on the IDE to tell you if something initialized prove it to yourself by examining your code, or print out the value of thumbs before you use it every time.

The only other exception possibilities at that line are ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if j > thumbs.length-1. But again, that's not a NPE. If title was null, that's fine and not an exception.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the thumbs[] hasn't been initialized doing something like:

String [] thumbs = new String [properties.getLength()];

Though it's hard to say - your code doesn't show your declaration of this array.

Comment: No no i alreadt checked it..if i didnt initialized means it vil show in the ECLIPSE

Comment: Can you post the complete class?  If title was null, you wouldn't get a null pointer exception, so thumbs[j] must be null.  The only way it could be null is if it wasn't init'd properly.  Like I say, impossible to know for sure without seeing the whole class file :-)

Comment: I got the another resolution for it. Just i create a ArrayList and add titles one by one to list.. Now I am getting all the values of titles in the array List.. But string Array Throws NPE only..